# Is 'unsightly experience' correct way of explaining seeing some ugly thing

Tags: relative-clauses

I would like to know if I say ' I had an unsightly experience on my morning walk today',  would this sound correct?  I want to explain how I saw something so ugly on my walk today that it ruined my walk. 
Thanks.

Comment: I can only read [one instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+unsightly+experience%22) of *unsightly experience* in Google Books, and it's obviously from a non-native Anglophone. But there are several instances of [*an **unseemly** experience*,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+unseemly+experience%22&tbm=bks&ei=DNfKXIPLDOyW1fAPr46EwAw&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiDgfi-4fzhAhVsSxUIHS8HAcg4ChDx0wMINQ&biw=1472&bih=750&dpr=1.2) as I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Unsightly means unpleasant to the sight. An experience,
good or bad, generally involves more senses of perception  and a very bad one may  cause a sense of fear or danger. A bad   experience may involve an unsightly and dangerous place, for instance.

> ***[Unsightly](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/unsightly)*** is a gentler way of saying ugly. Often something that is described as unsightly sticks out like a sore thumb in an otherwise attractive environment.
>
> - *A yard full of weeds and broken-down cars in a well-groomed neighborhood is unsightly. Magazine advertisements highlight products that promise to remove or hide unsightly blemishes and scars, restoring your skin to its previous beauty.*

(Vocabulary.com)

Answer (score -1):

Something that is unsightly must be ugly. I'm not sure if you can use **an unsightly experience** because I think that unsightly has something to do with a scene or a thing that can be seen. For example: *an unsightly building*.

You could say: **Today, I had an unpleasant experience during my morning walk**

Please correct me on my mistakes. We are all here to learn :)

Comment: The thing you saw was unsightly, not the experience of seeing it.

Comment: @KateBunting exactly! So, can the OP use _I had an unsightly experience_ or does s/he have to change it to _I experienced an unsightly *thing*_?

Comment: No, they can't. It would have to be _I saw something unsightly_ or, as you suggest,  _I had an unpleasant experience_.

Comment: Someone downvoted me on my answer. How disheartening!